# Loading dll from resources fails

Tags: c#, wpf

My application depends on a few DLLs. I put them all in resources and than on start of the application I load them using a method I found on the web:

```
public static void LoadDllsFromResources()
        {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, a) =>
        {
            string dllName = a.Name.Contains(',')
                                ? a.Name.Substring(0, a.Name.IndexOf(','))
                                : a.Name.Replace(".dll", "");

            dllName = dllName.Replace(".", "_");

            if (dllName.EndsWith("_resources")) return null;

            System.Resources.ResourceManager rm =
                new System.Resources.ResourceManager(
                    "DesktopDashboard" + ".Properties.Resources",
                    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            byte[] bytes = (byte[])rm.GetObject(dllName);

            return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(bytes);
        };
    }
```

It worked fine for me until I tried to add WPFToolkitExtended.dll. Than my app throws an error. What makes this DLL so special?

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Set connectionId threw an
>   exception.' Line number '4' and line position '37'. --->
>   System.InvalidCastException: [A]Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.BusyIndicator cannot
>   be cast to [B]Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.BusyIndicator. Type A originates from
>   'WPFToolkit.Extended, Version=1.7.4644.13122, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4' in the context 'LoadNeither' in a
>   byte array. Type B originates from 'WPFToolkit.Extended,
>   Version=1.7.4644.13122, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4' in the context 'LoadNeither' in a
>   byte array.    at
>   DesktopDashboard.LogoutWindow.System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(Int32
>   connectionId, Object target)    at
>   MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetConnectionId(Object root,
>   Int32 connectionId, Object instance)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e,
>   IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel
>   accessLevel, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext
>   parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator)    at
>   DesktopDashboard.LogoutWindow.InitializeComponent()    at
>   DesktopDashboard.LogoutWindow..ctor()    at
>   DesktopDashboard.MainWindow.ContextMenuItemLogout_Click(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
>   RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(Object arg)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object
>   userData)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run()    at
>   DesktopDashboard.App.Main(String[] args)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is loading the same assembly more than once.  That's a problem when you use Assembly.Load(byte[]), the CLR cannot help you figure out that an assembly was already loaded.  The technical term is that such an assembly was loaded without a "loading context".  What goes wrong next is that the same type is no longer compatible, type identity includes not just the namspace name and type name but also the assembly it came from.

It is your job to ensure that you return the exact same assembly reference when the same assembly is requested.  Best thing to do is to keep a `Dictionary<string, Assembly>` that keeps track of such assemblies.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why this happens only with this one dll? I handled the rest exactly the same way.

Comment: This happens, for one, when multiple assemblies reference this Xceed toolkit assembly.  Not unusual for a "toolkit" style assembly of course.  If you don't want to fix the problem then a Setup.exe is the obvious solution.  Advisable, toolkits are usually big and you really want to take advantage of ngen.exe

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on visual studio, you could add them to the project directly from the IDE. [Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes I'm using VS. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. This app works fine as long as the dll (already added to references) is next to the exe file, but I want to have it built into my exe file and load it from resources when the app starts - which successfully worked with other dlls.